# Unexpected behaviour text textFieldShouldBeginEditing / textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uitextfield

I have a `UItextField` called `textField` on a static cell tableView. That field contains a currency amount - like "$10,000.00".

When editing that amount, the currency and thousand grouping symbols are a bit in the way. Therefore I would like to remove those when the field becomes the first responder.

I do this in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

The first time I do this, everything works. The `textField`'s contents are reformatted without currency and thousand group separator.

On `textFieldDidEndEditing` I re-format the value into a proper currency string again. This also works.

The problem happens when I re-enter the field for a 2nd time. While debugging I can see the `textField.text` has changed into the string without currency symbol and grouping symbol, **but the display does not show that**. Although it did work the first time! The 2nd time it looks like there is a mismatch between what is on the screen and what value the debugger sees.

I've tried things like:

- tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates()
- textView.setNeedsDisplay

... but this does not work.

So I copied the code that removes the currency formatting in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to a new delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing`.

Then everything worked fine. I could tap other controls and back to the textField a number of times and each time the control would lose its formatting when entered and would be restored to a formatted currency string after losing focus.

So I decided to delete the method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. But then things broke down again! It looks like I have to implement both `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` as well as `textFieldDidBeginEditing` to be able to prepare a `textField`'s contents for user-editing?

Is this a bug?

```
extension Double {
    public func doubleToString(numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style, decimals: Int, withThousandSeparator: Bool) -> String {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = numberStyle
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = decimals
        if !withThousandSeparator {
            numberFormatter.groupingSeparator = ""
        }
        return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: self)) ?? ""
    }
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === self.textField {
        textField.text = amount.doubleToString(numberStyle: .decimal, decimals: 2, withThousandSeparator: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do in textFieldShouldBeginEditing ? Just return true ?

Comment: Would you mind adding the code to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should try textField's text changed event, attaching code below :

**Add target on textField for text changed :**

```
self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

**Function for textField's text change :**

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    if textField === self.textField
    {
         //try formatting here
    }
}
```